# Bootstrap 3 Vertical Image Alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a really basic html structure that has a single row split in to two even columns. I have two equally sized images and require one to be horizontally and vertically centred in each column.

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <img src="example.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <img src="example.png" />
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

A wireframe of how the pages should look is as follows:

[image]

I thought this could be achieved through bootstraps centre classes. I have also tried custom css using flexbox. I feel I am missing something as I expected this to be fairly simple but my images float at the top of the page.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Layout them as a table in CSS

```
.container .row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.container .col-md-6 {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Taken from https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: Thanks, but the images still hug the top of the page. any other ideas?